# Runtime node not connecting to Admin node

Tags: curity

I tried to create a runtime node. Downloaded the cluster file from the curity admin console and added it to runtime node. I also modified the startup.properties file to mention `ADMIN=false`.

When I start the runtime node I this error:

> 2021-12-09T14:07:00:166+0000 INFO    {core-job-scheduler-2}
> se.curity.identityserver.cluster.RuntimeNodeClusterManager - Setting
> cluster mode to Runtime, attempting to connect to master: xx.xx.xx.xx
> port 6789 2021-12-09T14:07:00:180+0000 INFO    {conf-Thread-10-42}
> se.curity.identityserver.cluster.RuntimeNodeClusterManager - Runtime
> not connected to admin. Connect to admin failed
> 2021-12-09T14:07:03:168+0000 DEBUG   {core-job-scheduler-2}
> se.curity.identityserver.cluster.ClusterManager - HA status:
> state='NONE', nodes=[] ^C

Answer (score 0):

What environment / network setup are you using, eg are nodes able to contact each other?

I usually follow these steps when setting up a development cluster:

- Set an environment variable of `SERVICE_ROLE=admin` before running the admin node
- Download the cluster-configuration.xml file as you've done
- Copy it into the /opt/idsvr/etc/init folder of a new runtime node
- Set an environment variable with a different role, eg `SERVICE_ROLE=default`, before running the runtime node

Here is a clustered [Docker compose setup](https://github.com/curityio/dynamic-user-routing/blob/main/docker-compose.yml) I put together a while ago, where nodes are on the same Docker network. Hopefully it is useful to compare against, and when the system is deployed it should look like this:

[image: Deployed System]

Further info is available in [this tutorial](https://curity.io/resources/learn/intro-to-cluster/). Feel free to post back if this does not fix your problem, but tell us more about your infrastructure setup.